# Parallel and asynchronous results

Tags: python

I want to SSH into N hosts to check the output of a command. A successful run will return in ~2 seconds while timeouts may take 40 seconds each. As we can see for 5 hosts, best case is 10 seconds while worst case is more than 3 minutes.

So I want to **transparently execute them in parallel** and when the last one has finished, I want to examine the outputs (**and errors** if they happened). And I dont want individual results to slow down the whole process.

---

Heres the function I need to run in parallel:

```
def fetch_results_from_ssh( host):
    try:
        a = login_and_fetch_values()
        return a
    except:
        throw Exception("something")
```

Heres the kind of wrapping I want to make above function asynchronous:

```
result_futures = []
for i in ["h1","h2","h3"]
    result_futures.append( async( fetch_results_from_ssh( i))

for i in result_futures:
    if i.worked_fine():
        print "host " + host + "value: " + i.value #yes, i did not define host anywhere
    else:
        print "host " + host + "error: " + i.error
```

---

How do I execute it in parallel? I prefer something doable with **standard library**, even if I need to code more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads or the multiprocess (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) to run operations in parallel. The same end can be achieved via fabric http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/ as well.